# convert function to decorator django

Tags: django, django-views

I want to do this:

```
@friendship_required
```

or

```
@friendship_required(request)
```

Can any one help me make this simple function into a decorator I think I will be using it a lot and feel it's better to make it into a decorator, or how I may set the `return` statement if `hasattr` is in my settings file? Thanks

```
def friendship_checker(request):
    if hasattr(request.user,'friend'):
        pass
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/access-denied')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from functools import wraps

def friendship_checker(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(request.user, 'friend'):
            return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/access-denied')

    return wrapped
```

So, to decorate a view:

```
@friendship_checker
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: andrea how will i use this to decorate this view def profile(request):

Comment: I added an example to my answer.